# Projecting an IEnumerable inside an Projected IQueryable making N Requests to the Database

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

I'm making an Asp.net Core Api and one of the Actions of the Controller i need to return an IQueryable of a DTO, but one of the properties is an IEnumerable of another DTO in a relationship one to many in the database model of EF.
For example:

```cs
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
        public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

And the DTO

```cs
    public class CustomerDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<OrderDTO> Orders { get; set; }
    }

    public class OrderDTO
    {
        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

This is just a simple example because in my application there is alot more fields on each table and i cannot expose everything to the frontend application, that's why i'm using DTOs.

I'm using the Select to Project each element to the DTO, there is no problem there because i can see on the ASP.NET Core Web Server output that the system is only making one request to the database (to get the Customers), but the problem comes when i try to project the OrdersDTO inside the CustomerDTO. What's happening is for example if i have 100 customers the EF will make 101 requests to the database. (1 to get the Customers and 100 to get the Orders for each customer)

```cs
   [HttpGet]
   [EnableQuery]
   public IEnumerable<CustomerDTO> Get()
      {
        return context.Customer
        .Select(s => new CustomerDTO
        {
           Id = s.Id,
           Name = s.Name,
           Orders = s.Orders.Select(so => new OrderDTO
           {
              OrderNumber = so.OrderNumber
           })
         });
      }
```

If i call ToList() before i project the elements using Select it will make only one request to the Database (as intended), but i need to return an IQueryable because i'm using OData, so that the frontend application can execute queries directly to the database even if is just a DTO

I already tried putting like this

```cs
     Orders = s.Orders.Any() ? s.Orders.Select(so => new OrderDTO
       {
         OrderNumber = so.OrderNumber
       }) : new List<OrderDTO>()
```

It solved the problem partially because if out of the 100 customers theres is only 50 that have orders the EF will only make 50 requests to the Database.

I would like to know if there is a solution to this problem because i don't want the application doing hundreds of queries to the database each time some user calls this endpoint of the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `ToList()` when projecting the inner collection.

```
       Orders = s.Orders.Select(so => new OrderDTO
       {
          OrderNumber = so.OrderNumber
       }).ToList() // <--
```

First because `CustomerDTO.Orders` property type is `List<OrderDTO>`, so the code does not compile w/o that.

But even it wasn't (let say it's `IEnumerable<OrderDTO>`), you still need `ToList` in order to get EF Core 2.1 introduced [Optimization of correlated subqueries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#optimization-of-correlated-subqueries)
:

> We have improved our query translation to avoid executing "N + 1" SQL queries in many common scenarios in which the usage of a navigation property in the projection leads to joining data from the root query with data from a correlated subquery. The optimization requires buffering the results from the subquery, and we require that you modify the query to opt-in the new behavior.

Note the last sentence - *"we **require** that you modify the query to **opt-in** the new behavior"*. Then documentation contains an example and continues with:

> By including `ToList()` in the right place, you indicate that buffering is appropriate for the Orders, which enable the optimization

Comment: Thank you very much!! It solved the problem! I was trying to find a solution for days and didn't notice this new improvement to EF Core 2.1

Actually there was a typo on my part, it was `IEnumerable<OrderDTO>` in fact